# Explanation of $\int\frac{r}{\sigma^2}\exp\big(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\big)\; dr=-\exp\big(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\big)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can you please explain this equality?

$$\int\frac{r}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\; dr=-\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The key observation is that the given integrand is (up to a scalar multiple) of the form $g'(x)f'(g(x))$. Recognizing functions and their derivatives is necessary to make this observation - in particular, that $\exp'=\exp$ and the derivative of a power is (up to a scalar multiple) the next power lower (e.g. $(r^2)'=2r^1$). The rest of the constants involved are just scalings in the domain and codomain that can be handled after the key insight is seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check that an indefinite integral is equal to a function
$$
\int f(x) \; dx= F(x) \quad (+C)
$$
you can simply check that $F'(x) = f(x)$. In your example you check that 
$$
\frac{d}{dr} [-\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)] = -\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\frac{d}{dr} \frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2} \\
= \exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\frac{r}{\sigma^2}
$$

---

If you don't like this, then you can also find the integral using the substitution method with $\displaystyle{u = \frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. So then
$$\begin{align}
du &= \frac{-2r}{2\sigma^2}dr \quad \Rightarrow\\
-du &= \frac{r}{\sigma^2}dr
\end{align}
$$
So the integral becomes
$$
\int -e^u \; du.
$$
This you can probably find.

Comment: If it's not too much of a bother could I please ask you to elaborate on the substitution method in this example? I tried it myself and that's where I got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: @Mankochka: I added more details.

Comment: @Mankochka: Glad to help.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

A primitive function of $\frac{r}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ is $-\exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$.